# How to customize label color of material ui Textfield when out of focus?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize Textfiled of material-ui

I was able to change everything I wanted except the color of the label when out of focus

[Here image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emsGg.png)

by defualt the color is black (when out of focus)
How could I change that?

here is my code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
notchedOutline: {
    color: "red !important", // label foucus color 
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "red !important" // border color when out of focus

},
cssOutlinedInput: {
    color: "green !important", // text color when out of focus
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: `yellow !important` // border color when Focused
    }

},
cssFocused: {
    color: "red !important" // text and label color when focued
},
```

});

```
 <TextField
                    id="outlined-basic"
                    label="Username"
                    variant="outlined"
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    error={usernameError.isInvalid ? true : false}
                    helperText={usernameError.errorHelper}
                    onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, username: e.target.value })}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssLabel,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused
                        }
                    }}
                    InputProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
                        },
                        startAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position="start">
                                <AccountCircleSharpIcon />
                            </InputAdornment>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already selecting the correct class `root: classes.cssLabel` in `InputLabelProps`, but your shared `styles` doesn't have the styles for it.

```
InputLabelProps={{
  classes: {
    root: classes.cssLabel,
    focused: classes.cssFocused
  }
}}
```

Adding below in the `makeStyles` should fix the problem.

```
cssLabel: {
  color: "red"
}
```